# User Mapping Refresh

Tags: opshub

On the first migration attempt, I had two users created in TFS Online that had the same display name. OpsHub is apparently not able to deal with multiple users having the same display name. In my attempt to get past this, I have changed the user display name, deleted the user, and reinstalled OpsHub, all to avail. OpsHub keeps showing the original set of (duplicate) TFS users rather than the current set. How does one do a clean uninstall of OpsHub such that it does not use cached information?

Comment: It seems more like the TFS Cache is the one that needs to be refreshed. Turn off the OpsHub utility.
- Close all instances of Visual Studio (if any)
- Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents of the below folders
      1)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache
      2)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
      3)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache. Restart the utility and try to load the users again. (Do this on the machine where the OpsHub utility has been installed)

Comment: I reinstalled the program again - this time making sure to delete the cache, and it worked. The current list of users was obtained and I was able to successfully migrate the projects.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. :)